# UIView, AutoLayout and strange behaviors

Tags: objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I have a strange behavior with UIView, subviews and AutoLayout. Here's the scenario:

I have a XIB file containing a number of subviews. I have a subview on the bottom of the UIView. The strange thing is: all subviews are placed correctly on an iPhone 3.5" screen, but the bottom one, that lies behind the bottom margin of the screen.

I've checked the constraints and all of them seems to be ok, because on other XIB file I have the same subviews and are represented ok.

¿any ideas?

Comment: how are you loading the subviews from the Xib?

Comment: the problematic subview is an IBOutlet, so it's loaded directly this way.

Comment: yeah but is the Xib a view controller Xib, or are you loading it separately, e.g. loadNibNamed ?

Comment: yep, it's a UIViewController

Comment: probably going to need to see screenshots of the Xib and constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was an issue with corrupted files.